# Date format changes on UpdateView in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, datepicker

I have a form to create an object where the date input format is 'dd/mm/yyyy', when I submit the form, it is saved without any problem, but when I edit this object, the date shows as 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

settings.py

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y')
```

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    created_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y',],
    widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker form-control', 'placeholder':'Select a date'}), required=False)
```

models.py

```
created_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Created on")
```

views.py

```
class MyEdit(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyForm
    template_name_suffix = '_edit'
    success_message = '...'
```

and in my template I use

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true
  });
```

Comment: Is the format correct if you remove the datepicker ?

Comment: The problem is still the same, no change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that the field is responsible for validation, but it is the widget that is responsible for displaying the value. So you need to pass [`format`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateInput.format) there too:

```
widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker form-control', 'placeholder':'Select a date'}), required=False, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I used in the end `widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs={'class':'datepicker form-control', 'placeholder':'Select a date'}), required=False)` (with format='%d/%m/%Y' inside the DateInput parenthesis, otherwise it thrown an error)